# Creating Custom Options page in wordpress and adding sub_menu_page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Below is my code, the code generates a user custom options menu page, after adding the sub menu page, when I click the sub menu option, the page refreshes but the sub menu page content is not visible, only the main page content sticks. Please help me to where I am wrong. Do I have to `register_setting` or any thing else....

```
<?php
  // create custom plugin settings menu
  add_action('admin_menu', 'omr_create_menu');
  add_action('admin_menu', 'omr_create_submenu');

  function omr_create_menu() {
    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('My Menu Page', 'Main Menu', 'administrator', __FILE__,   'main_menu_page', 'favicon.ico');
  }
?>
<?php 
  function main_menu_page() {
    global $title;
?>
  <h2><?php echo $title;?></h2>
  My New Menu Page!!
<?php
  }

  function omr_create_submenu(){
    add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'My SubMenu Page', 'My Submenu', 'administrator', 'my_new_submenu', 'my_submenu_page');
  }
  function my_submenu_page() {
    global $title;
?>
  <h2><?php echo $title;?></h2>
  My New Submenu Page!!
<?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the same content page for both menu and submenu with `_file_`, so you don't see the sbu muen page.

works both:

```
add_menu_page('My Menu Page', 'Main Menu', 'administrator', __FILE__,   
     'main_menu_page', 'favicon.ico');
add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'My SubMenu Page', 'My Submenu', 'administrator',  
      'my_new_submenu', 'my_submenu_page');
```

**and**

```
add_menu_page('My Menu Page', 'Main Menu', 'administrator', 8, 'main_menu_page', 
   'favicon.ico'); 
add_submenu_page(8, 'My SubMenu Page', 'My Submenu', 'administrator', 1, 
   'my_submenu_page');
```

Comment: so kindly tell me how to resolve this, even if i edit __FILE__, it says "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.", how to resolve the issue.

Comment: when you say 'edit FILE' you mean you change to another file, right? and do you have problems with main menu page??

Comment: no i dont have problems with main menu page, when i click on sub menu option the text to display which i wrote in sub_menu_page function does not appear but text in  main_menu_page function appear and does not change. well i tried the bellow code, for that i got the abode error saying you dont have permissions.        add_menu_page('Mahesh Chari', 'Mahesh Chari', 'administrator', 8, array(&$this,'overview'));
    add_submenu_page(8, 'Settings', 'Settingss', 'administrator', 1, array(&$this,'settings'));

Comment: hi,,I just test your code in the question in my local WP. there is no problem...it shows both main page and sub page correctly.

Comment: the same code i changed for the code which i wrote, for _FILE_ i changed it too '8', if im not wrong it is menu_slug, and for sub_menu_page add i wrote     add_menu_page('My Menu Page', 'Main Menu', 'administrator', 8, 'main_menu_page', 'favicon.ico');
    add_submenu_page(8, 'My SubMenu Page', 'My Submenu', 'administrator', 1, 'my_submenu_page');

Comment: I don't know why you are using number 8 and 1,,,these two should be php files where the contents are shown.

Comment: from the codex the 8 and 1 positions are for mentioning menu slugs, the coder used numerals instead of unique text.... right?

Comment: no...the menu slugs only accept string which will be page name. you can see the page name in url bar when you click the menu.

Comment: ok this is the code of that guy.....    function Maheshchari()
    {
        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'my_admin_menu'));
    }
 
    function my_admin_menu()
    { //create a main admin panel
  //create a sub admin panel link above
        add_menu_page('Mahesh Chari', 'Mahesh Chari', 'administrator', 8, array(&$this,'overview'));
        add_submenu_page(8, 'Settings', 'Settingss', 'administrator', 1, array(&$this,'settings'));